# How to select files with spaces in their name in a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

When using `gnome-terminal` which is the default on Linux Mint, I can select files using a double click.  For example:

```
user@hostname $> ls

1.file.name
2-file-name
3 file name with spaces
```

This approach works for examples 1 and 2 above.  When I try and do the same for example 3, it will highlight a single word.  Further double clicking selects the entire line including the newline character at the end.  So when pasting into a command, it can have unintended consequences.

**What I'm after is quick way of selecting `3 file name with spaces` in my example above.**

I've tried:

```
ls -Q

"1.file.name"
"2-file-name"
"3 file name with spaces"
```

And then trying the double click method but this doesn't help.

Therefore is it possible to do it with the `gnome-terminal` or is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't use gnome-terminal, but have you tried `ls --escape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general tab of in the options of `gnome-terminal`, there is a configration item to specify the characters that should be selected, when selecting (with doubleclick):

[image: gt]

Add a single space to the list. Now, with `ls -Q` the whole part that is inside the quotes will be selected.

**But notice**, now, a space no longer delimits words! It may solve that problem, but raises a lot of others. Try it out.

Comment: It does work, but now I entire lines are selected (as you'd expect) when I didn't get that behaviour before e.g. `ls -l`.  However, as you stated `ls -Q` does mean items within quotes can be selected.